# missing header "content-type" on POST request swagger node.js

Tags: node.js, http-headers, swagger, swagger-ui

Sending a **POST** request with an body in **Swagger**, nothing arrives in request... I think the problem is because it doesn't have the header "**content-type**"

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/896kA.png

Testing the same request in **postman** arrives normally(why has the header).

stopped sending the header when I added authorization in swaggerOptions, specifically "**openapi**", "**schemes**" and "**security**"

swaggerOptions.json

```
const swaggerOptions = {
    definition: {  
        openapi: '3.0.0',  
        info: {            
            version: "1.0.0",
            title: "Diniz API",
            description: "Rest API Diniz",
            servers: ['http://localhost:5000']
        },
        components: {
            securitySchemes: {
                bearerAuth: {
                    type: 'apiKey',
                    name: 'Authorization',
                    scheme: 'bearer',
                    in: 'header',
                },
            }
        },
        security: [{ 
            bearerAuth: [], 
        }],
    },
    apis: ['routes/*.js']
}
```

Comment: Please post the annotations of the `/signup` endpoint. From the screenshot it looks like the endpoint is annotated using OpenAPI 2.0 keywords (e.g. an `in: body` parameter) whereas it should use OpenAPI 3.0 keywords (i.e. [`requestBody`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/)) to match the OpenAPI version specified in your `swaggerOptions`.

Comment: here is my notations from /signup https://i.imgur.com/HupRIp6.png
what am I doing wrong? tried to read the docs but didn't understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `/signup` annotations, replace the `parameters` section with the following `requestBody` section:

```
*      ...
*      summary: Create new account
*
*      requestBody:
*        required: true
*        content:
*          application/json:
*            schema:
*              type: object
*              required:
*                - name
*                - email
*                - ...   # add the rest of the required properties
*              properties:
*                name:
*                  type: string
*                ...     # add the rest of the properties
```